# How to convert a dictionary with main text and multiple sub texts

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a text file. The file contains lines. After a few lines there is a single blank line. This line is used to indicate the end of a section.
The First Blank line is used to indicate the end of the main text and the start of the sub text. When another blank line is detected, it means the sub text portion has finished and a new main text portion starts.

I have written some code to solve this problem in python. The main text serves as the key in a python dictionary whereas the sub texts serves as the value of that key. The multiple sub texts are stored as a list.

In the code, the variable's are as follows:

```
 word  : Empty dictionary
 value : List  containing the sub headings
 key   : Contains the current main heading
 i     : set to 1 at the start to get the first line, when a 
         new line is detected, it changes to -1. When another 
         empty line is detected, it changes to 1 again.
```

Here 1 means line contains Main Text and -1 means Sub Text.

Here if i is 1, the main text is added to the key. 
If it is -1, the sub text is added to the value list.

If we detect another empty line, we check if i is -1, if it is true, we set update the word dictionary with {key : value}.

We then change the sign of i again.

My problem is that the program seems to be in an infinite loop.

Thank you kindly for reading my problem. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import json

class test1:

    word = {}
    value = []
    i = 1
    key = ''
    filepath = 'we.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
            lines = fp.readlines()
            for j in range(0, len(lines)):
                    currentline = lines[j]
                    if i == 1:
                            key = currentline

                    if currentline in ['\n', '\r\n']:
                            if i == -1:
                                    word.update({key: value})

                    i = i * -1

                    if i == -1:
                            value.append(currentline)
            print(word)
```

The Output should be

mainText11 : ['subtext1', 'subtext2']
   maintext2  : ['subtext1', 'subtext2', 'subtext3']

The we.txt contains the following:

```
                  main heading1

                  sub heading1
                  sub heading2

                  main heading2
```

UPDATE :
I have made some changes to the code. But the problem remains.

Comment: Please paste the `we.txt` file so that we can replicate your code.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over the lines of the file, here is what I'd do:

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines() # read all the lines from the file
    for line in lines: # loop over the list containing all lines
        # same as in your while loop
```

In your code `line` doesn't change inside the `while` loop, that's why that never ends, you never read more than one line of the file.

---

Edit:

Here is your code (I tried to make as few changes as possible to it):

```
word = {}
value = []
i = 1
key = ''
filepath = 'we.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for j in range(0, len(lines)):
                currentline = lines[j]

                if currentline in ['\n', '\r\n']:
                        if i == -1:
                                word.update({key: value})
                                value = [] # start with empty value for the next key
                        i = i * -1 # switch only if we read a newline
                        continue # skip to next line (the newline shouldn't be stored)

                # store values only after we know, it's not an empty line
                if i == 1:
                        key = currentline()
                if i == -1:
                        value.append(currentline)

        word.update({key: value}) # update also with the last values
        print(word)
```

The values will have newlines at the end. To get rid of those I'd chance the first lines of the loop to:

```
                currentline = lines[j].strip() # strip line, so it doesn't end with '\n'
                if not currentline: # if currentline is empty
```

Also, you could move the entire loop outside the with.

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Thank You for your Comment. I ran the code, the infinite loop is not there but the output is wrong.    {'main heading1\n': ['main heading1\n', 'sub heading1\n', '\n']} is the output.   This output is wrong.

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain all the code, so now it outputs the correct values.